# Web page dialog in Android webview is partialy out of screen and can not see even move/zoom the page

Tags: android, dialog, android-webview

The details is :there's a page loaded in Android Webview with default fitting window width and can be zoomed out/in.
Since an element showing is too small to see clearly and be exactly clickable,user will zoom in the page. After that,when user clicks the element,a webpage dialog pops out, which is not a native dialog.The tricky is,although the dialog is also zoomed in but it is not at center of the screen and some part of it keeps being out of screen even after scrolling right/left of the page.

Anyone known how to fix that?

```
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setTextZoom(100);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    myWebView.setInitialScale(100);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

Comment: Any screenshots? Any code? Anything?

Comment: Is the page/script working perfectly in desktop browser?

Comment: It works perfectly on desktop browser and if the page is not zoomed in before the dialog pops out,the dialog pops out at center of screen.

Comment: How it renders if you do not use setTextZoom(), and setIntialZoom() ? In my case, it was alot to do in javascript rather than webview to show the web page perfectly, like padding, margins, alignment etc.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue. Adding following fixed for me.

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
  webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```